# Media query isn't working properly

Tags: html, css

i'm new to this front-end designing, everything is going good so far but i'm stuck at one point and know how to solve it, hopefully someone will help me out here.

So here i have written this CSS code:

```
/*  Universal Reset 
**********************************/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700|Slabo+27px);

*{ /*Universal selector */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #727272;
    font-family: "Lato", "open-sans", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: #FFF9C4;
    color: #727272;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    .wrapper{
        background-color: #00BCD4;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 748px;

    }
}
```

My problem is that whenever i reduce the screen size below 768px, the page remains same as if there is no media query, and then i go on and reduce it below 688px then the page works according to code. Why is this happening?

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Le Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="site-header">
        <h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1>
        <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="page.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?  Are you sure that your .wrapper actually is taking up more than 688px of width in full-screen mode?

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/6a748br4/embedded/result/

Comment: Nope, it's not taking more than 688px in full screen mode. How do i post it? It showing some error like i need to put more contents

Comment: @ uʍopǝpısdn - I see, but i use a shortcut like ctrl+shft+M in mozilla developer browser to check responsiveness, which is also accurate.

Comment: I put all of your code in one file and it runs perfectly as it is supposed to by transitioning at 768 pixels.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle of your exact code and it works as it is supposed to no problem. https://jsfiddle.net/of3qdkj4/

Comment: I am using Responsive Design View shortcut (ctrl+shift+M) in mozilla developer browser to check responsiveness, here it doesn't run as it's supposed to. Could this be a failure on browser's part?

Comment: What are you trying to do or accomplish? On Jsfiddle it's working perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/00b728sb/

Comment: Got it. It was due to the zooming that i was experiencing the problem. My browser was zoomed out to 75% and that is where it all got messed up. If anybody else is facing this problem, just check the zoom and make sure it is always at 100%. This little thing got me.